# pydev code coverage reports zero

Tags: code-coverage, pydev

I am using eclipse Mars with pydev.
the python coverage module version is 3.7.1. It is installed with pip.
On the code coverage view there is no checkbox for "Enable code coverage for new launches?". The text is there, just there is no control associated.
I see "0%" everywhere in the Cover column, even after refreshing with hand.

The file /home/mag/workspace-mars/.metadata/.plugins/org.python.pydev.debug/coverage/.coverage is 50 byte binary. If I remove it before running unit tests, it reapears. My guess that this file is empty.

I did delete all interpreters in Pydev/Interpreters/Python interpreters and find them again with "quick auto-config.

Answer (score 0):

This was an overlook from my part. There is actually a checkbox near "Enable coverage for new launches", just it is not visible.
I have clicked above the other two checkboxes, and voila. A check sign appeared, and coverage reports are shown.